# How to create function to avoid infinite loop on recursive PSQL

Tags: postgresql, recursion, triggers, reference, recursive-query

I have a problem, I have a self referenced table of employees with each respective manager and sometimes for human error, it creates an infinite loop.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    job varchar(255),
    manager_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees (id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Below are the rows I'm using to test the infinite loop. ID 1 to> ID 5 to> ID 7 to> ID 1.....

```
INSERT INTO employees (id,name,manager_id,job)VALUES
    (1,  'Max', 5, 'CEO'),
    (2,  'Jeremy', 5, 'Junior Developer'),
    (3,  'Allen', 5, 'Intern'),
    (4,  'Lucas', 5, 'Developer'),
    (5,  'John', 7, 'Manager'),
    (6,  'Creed', 7, 'DevOps Engineer'),
    (7,  'Anna', 1, 'VP'),
    (8,  'Logan', 1, 'Manager'),
    (9,  'Ted', 8, 'Data Analyst'),
    (10, 'Jensen', 8, 'Developer');
```

I tried creating a trigger after update but for some reason it didn`t work.

```
create or replace function if_atu_employee() returns trigger as
$$      
DECLARE         
        hier RECORD;
begin   
        IF NEW.manager_id IS NULL THEN 
                return NEW;
        END IF; 

        WITH RECURSIVE managers AS (
                SELECT id, name, manager_id, job
                FROM employees
                WHERE id = NEW.id
        UNION ALL
                SELECT e.id, e.name, e.manager_id, e.job
                FROM employees e 
                JOIN managers ON e.manager_id = managers.id
        )
    cycle ID set is_cycle using path
        SELECT INTO hier id FROM managers WHERE is_cycle limit 1;

    IF hier IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE employees SET manager_id = NULL WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END IF;
        
        return NEW;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
create trigger if_tr_employee after update on employees for each row execute procedure if_atu_employee();
```

Do someone know what I'm doing wrong at the function?

Comment: As the ceo is the highest in the hierarchy, the mangerid should be null. but i don't see, why do you need a trigger at all. lets say Alan number 3 switches Manages what do need to update  or insert trigger for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems to work, for both INSERT and UPDATE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_check_loop()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        _id INT;
    BEGIN
        WITH RECURSIVE managers AS (
                SELECT id
                     , name
                     , ARRAY[manager_id] manager_ids
                     , job
                FROM employees
                WHERE id = NEW.id
        UNION ALL
                SELECT e.id
                     , e.name
                     , managers.manager_ids || e.manager_id,
                       e.job
                FROM employees e
                    JOIN managers ON e.manager_id = managers.id
        )
    SELECT NEW.id
    INTO _id
    FROM managers
    WHERE ARRAY(SELECT e FROM unnest(manager_ids) u(e) ORDER BY e )
              <>
          ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT e FROM unnest(manager_ids) u(e) ORDER BY e )
    LIMIT 1;

    IF FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Loop detected for id %', _id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER tr_loop AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION tr_check_loop();
```

Checking the array, containing the path, for non-distinct values should detect the loop. And it does need just one loop, so it stops as soon as it finds an issue. It's also raising an exception because the code never nows who the correct manager is. Setting a default NULL is not something I would recommend because it could take weeks or even months before you find out that your data has been screwed.